# Что означает точка с запятой в словарной статье?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, значение-слов, лексикография, точка-с-запятой

В словарных статьях часто можно встретить разделение слов запятой и точкой с запятой. Например, в Большом толковом словаре:

> НЕПУТЁВЫЙ, -ая, -ое. Разг. Легкомысленный, беспутный; бестолковый,
> безалаберный.

Одни слова разделены запятыми, другие — точкой с запятой.

Ни в одном справочнике (например, Розенталя и т. п.) нет объяснения, для чего используется точка с запятой в словарной статье, что она означает, и почему в одних случая даётся разделение запятой, а в других — точкой с запятой.

В словаре Ожегова в предисловии сказано, что точкой с запятой отделяется оттенок значения.

> Отдельные значения в многозначных словах разделяются арабскими цифрами, а оттенки в значении, если они имеются, отделяются точкой с запятой.

Но что такое «оттенок значения» не понятно, нет нигде определения «оттенка значения». Более того, есть мнение, что это размытое понятие у которого вообще научного определения в лингвистике не существует.

В Словаре русского языка в 4 томах РАН Евгеньевой сказано, что после точки с запятой идут синонимы.

> В тех случаях, когда слово в толкуемом значении имеет синонимы, они приводятся в качестве дополнительной характеристики слова вслед за толкованием значения после точки с запятой...

В Большом толковом словаре, в словаре Лопатина и ряде других словарей вообще нет никакой информации вначале о том, что значит точка с запятой в словарной статье, хотя она в этих словарях используется и очень активно.

Получается, авторы считают, что читатель должен понимать зачем она там стоит, исходя из грамматики русского языка, но в грамматике ничего не говорится о значении точки с запятой в словарной статье и о разнице между запятой и точкой с запятой в словарной статье.

Если это синонимы, то в случае примера выше (из Большого толкового словаря) очевидно, что, «безалаберный» не имеет того же значения, что и «непутёвый», и мы не можем использовать одно слово вместо другого. Да, синонимы часто не тождественны полностью, но в данном случае разница существенна.

Более того, есть словари, в которых идут отдельно синонимы и также есть слова после точки с запятой.

Проблема заключается в том, что если мы хотим точно установить значение слова, и если после точки с запятой идут синонимы, то мы их можем не считать частью определения и игнорировать.

Если же после точки с запятой идёт какой-то непонятный «оттенок значения», то для полного понимания слова мы всё-таки должны принять во внимание то, что идёт после точки с запятой.

Возможно, этому нет объяснения в грамматике, потому что это область знания лексикографии, отрасли языкознания, занимающейся составлением словарей.

Но было бы странно, чтоб составители словарей рассчитывали на то, что читатели — специалисты в этой науке. Ведь словарь пишется для простых людей, а не для учёных.

По лексикографии крайне мало материалов в Интернете, и трудно найти специалиста в реальной жизни, который может дать ответ на этот вопрос.

Интересно, что что похожее использование точки с запятой есть и в английском языке. Например, в известном Оксфордском словаре английского языка (привожу примеры из онлайн версии):

> **Regular** – 4. Used, done, or happening on a habitual basis; usual.

> **Also** – In addition; too.

> **Good** – 2.2 Healthy, strong, or well.

> **Bad** – 2.2 Unfavourable; adverse.

Видно, что одни слова разделяются запятыми, а другие точкой с запятой, и причина, по которой делается именно так, не ясна.

Однако складывается впечатление, что составители словарей руководствуются одним и тем же лексикографическим правилом.

**Разъясните, пожалуйста:**

- Что означает точка с запятой в словарных статьях?
- Какое правило регулирует использование запятой и точки с запятой в словарной статье? Если это общее правило в грамматике русского языка, дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку. Если это специализированное лексикографическое правило тоже дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку.
- Каково поредение термина «оттенок значения», использующегося в словаре Ожегова?
- **И главное:** нужно ли учитывать, то что написано после точки с запятой при раскрытии знания слова? Насколько я понимаю, если после точки с запятой идут синонимы, они не являются частью определения, и учитывать их не нужно. Но синонимы ли это на самом деле?